# How do I allow user to have email between apps, but not inside one app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, activemodel

I have next structure of my API application:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end
```

How do I allow user to have the same unique email BETWEEN apps, but not inside one app? If I write:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
  validates :email, uniquiness: true
end
```

It validates uniqueness of email globally among all Users, but I want it to validate only among the users of specific App model which User belongs to.

Other words, I want user to be able to sign up with same email for app with id 1 and app with id 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a scope to constrain this validation:

```
validates :email, uniquness: { scope: :app }
```

More information on `validates`, as well as the `uniquness` option can be found in the [Rails Validation Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Comment: Or use `validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :app` and read [ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)

Comment: It may also be helpful to add an index such as `add_index(:users, [:email, :app_id]), unique: true`.

Comment: @NicNilov I'm pretty sure `validates` is the preferred method for validation. `validates_uniqueness_of` is the old way of doing it. The same goes for `validates_length_of`, `validates_presence_of`, etc.

Comment: @Wes Foster a statement like this could certainly use a citation. Since you haven't given one, here it goes: [Rails sexy validations](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#sexy-validations). Thanks for pointing that out.